# Is it possible to check if Hyperthreading Sharing is enabled from a Virtual Machine?

Tags: vmware, esxi, vsphere

In the older versions of ESXi hosts, it was possible to view whether Hyperthreading Sharing is enable from the Virtual Machine as well as from host. In ESXi 6.5.0, I couldn't find following same steps.

Using : vSphere Web Client

[This](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/5.5/com.vmware.vsphere.resmgmt.doc/GUID-9FC94B43-FF06-48BD-AD19-D39719625BB9.html) will help in viewing as well as editing the Hyperthreading in 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

> In the older versions of ESXi hosts, it was possible to view whether Hyperthreading Sharing is enabled from the Virtual Machine as well as from host.

Hyperthreaded core sharing is not supported by ESXi 6.5

> Hyperthreaded core sharing is only supported for ESXi hosts version 5.0 and earlier.

Source: [Configure Hyperthreaded Core Sharing in the vSphere Web Client](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/5.5/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-101176D4-9866-420D-AB4F-6374025CABDA.html)